# Parse input and build a Dictionary/HashMap while parsing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, parsing, antlr

I am not sure if the title makes it clear what I want to do.

My input for my parser contains debug information about C source files. Some of the input looks e.g. like this:

```
L:C$main.c$41$1$10:C0C5
```

Which basically means that line `10` in the source file `main.c` corresponds with the memory address `C0C5`.

Here is an example what my AST looks like:

[image]

Which represents the input:

```
M:main
L:C$main.c$29$1$0:C09C
L:C$main.c$30$1$10:C0A2
M:divide
L:C$divice.c$31$1$10:C5A9
```

What I want are two Hash-Maps such that I can access these information quickly at runtime. But how can I now build such Hash-Maps and is it possible to do that at *parsetime*?

This is how I would like to use my parser:

```
public CDBFileParser getFileParser(String cdbFilePath)
{
    Stream stream                = File.OpenRead(cdbFilePath);
    ANTLRInputStream inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream(stream);
    CDBFileLexer lexer           = new CDBFileLexer(inputStream);
    CommonTokenStream tokens     = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    CDBFileParser parser         = new CDBFileParser(tokens);

    try
    {
        parser.TreeAdaptor = new CommonTreeAdaptor();
        parser.parseCDBFile();

        // All this works so far. Here comes the part I am looking for:

        Modules[] modules = parser.getModules();
        Dictionary<int, int> lineToAddress = modules[0].getLineToAddressMap();
        Dictionary<int, int> addressToLine = modules[0].getAddressToLineMap();

        int address = 0xC09C;

        System.Out.WriteLine( "Address 0xC09C is at line " + addressToLine.get(address) + " in " + modules[0].getName() );

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        printException(e);
    }

    return parser;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Address 0xC09C is at line 29 in main
```

Can anybody help?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to delete my question but maybe somebody else comes along to this post. I just made the transition to `ANTLR4` and it really is much simpler (so far at least).

In `ANTLR4` an interface (e.g. `ICDBFileListener`) is built for you which one can use to catch all information at *parsetime*:

```
namespace Parser
{
    public class CDBFileParserListener : ICDBFileListener
    {
        public void ExitModule_name(CDBFileParser.Module_nameContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ModuleName: " + context.GetText());
            // Add module to module-map and remember 
            // that current module is context.GetText()
        }

        public void ExitLine_number(CDBFileParser.Line_numberContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LineNumber: " + context.GetText());
            // Remember line number
        }

        public void ExitMemory_address(CDBFileParser.Memory_addressContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MemoryAddress: " + context.GetText());
            // Add linenumber <-> memoryaddress to maps
        }

        public Modules[] getModules() 
        {
            return m_modules;
        }
    }


}
```

And this is how it can be used:

```
    public CDBFileParser getFileParser(String cdbFilePath)
    {
        Stream stream                = File.OpenRead(cdbFilePath);
        AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(stream);
        CDBFileLexer lexer           = new CDBFileLexer(inputStream);            
        CommonTokenStream tokens     = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        CDBFileParser parser         = new CDBFileParser(tokens);

        try
        {
            CDBFileParserListener listener = new CDBFileParserListener();
            parser.AddParseListener(listener);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parser.parseCDBFile().ToStringTree());

            Dictionary<String, Module> modules = listener.Modules;

            Module main;
            modules.TryGetValue("main", out main);

            long line = main.getLineFromAddress(0xC09C);
            Console.WriteLine("0xC09C maps to " + line + " in  main.c");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            printException(e);
        }

        return parser;
    }
```